# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code when using Mapbox

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, mapbox

I have had the bellow error for some time now.

- I have tried creating new projects
- fixing the problem within the project
- Resetting all cocoa pods and more

And yet I have still not been able to get rid of this error.

**Error below:**

```
/Users/myUsername/Desktop/MapboxMap117/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MapboxMap117/Pods-MapboxMap117-frameworks.sh: line 114: local: `/Users/myUsername/Desktop/MapboxMap117/Pods/Mapbox-iOS-SDK/dynamic/826E141E-8875-3C3B-A106-2B772F8A0684.bcsymbolmap': not a valid identifier
```

> ```
> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
> ```

**I am also getting**: *(dont know if it is related)*

```
/Users/myUsername/Desktop/MapboxMap117/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MapboxMap117/Pods-MapboxMap117-frameworks.sh: line 114: local: `=': not a valid identifier
```

**How can I fix this error?**

*Note:*

It may have something to do with the code in my "mainVC" which I call "mapVC". I think this because when I get rid of all the code in there or comment it out the project does not get the error.

Comment: Hi can you show code segments related to the problem so we have some context to help you?

Comment: In addition to code samples, could you share which version of Xcode you are using, as well as which version of the Mapbox Maps SDK for iOS you are using?

Answer (score -1):

```
/Users/myUsername/Desktop/MapboxMap117/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MapboxMap117/Pods-MapboxMap117-frameworks.sh: line 114: local: `=': not a valid identifier
```

I believe the problem is likely coming from this. I have had a similar problem where I had spaces around the "=" when I got rid of the spaces it fix the problem.

- Go to that location and get rid of the spaces.
- build again

**Problem should be solved.**

Comment: i have the same problem and its not resolved doing this. 
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
Could you help?