# bcsymbolmap not a valid identifier?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I try and build my project I get the following error:

> /Users/username/Desktop/FinalAppPrj/Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods-FinalAppPrj/Pods-FinalAppPrj-frameworks.sh: line 114:
>   local:
>   `/Users/username/Desktop/FinalAppPrj/Pods/Mapbox-iOS-SDK/dynamic/826E141E-8875-3C3B-A106-2B772F8A0684.bcsymbolmap':
>   not a valid identifier

**What is the problem? and how do I solve it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by going to line 114 of some file and getting rid of the spacing around an = sign. I dont understand why this was causing problems but it fixed it.

**I got the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55173623/command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code-when-using-mapbox).**